# Display file contents

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am trying to display a full textfile in a batch file, but when I do it like this, it opens notepad.

```
@echo off
call YourText.txt
pause >nul
exit
```

I also tried

```
@echo off
more < YourText.txt
pause >nul
exit
```

Both with double quotes, and without. However, it doesn't work. Then, when I did it without `@echo off` it works, but it will display each line as:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Gebruiker\Mijn documenten\others\Bureaublad YourTextline 1
C:\Documents and Settings\Gebruiker\Mijn documenten\others\Bureaublad YourTextline 2
```

I already tried the `set /f` command without any luck.
Does anybody know how to import a full text file through a batch file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`type`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732507%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
type YourFile.txt
```

If you want it to pause between screens full of text, combine it with [`more`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733118%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) using the pipe `|` operator:

```
type YourFile.txt | more
```

or using `more` directly getting input from the text file or via redirection (first example courtesy of @MatthewStrawbridge in his comment):

```
more YourFile.txt
```

or

```
more < YourFile.txt
```

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge: Updated to show that option (presuming your `<` got swallowed up by markup). If you didn't include the redirection, can you post a link to docs that say that `more` works without it? The docs I linked all show some sort of redirection involved.

Comment: See the third line of the syntax in the `more` page you linked to.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge: Thanks. I missed the `<files>` buried at the end. :-) I'll edit my answer to include it (unless you want to post a separate answer).

Comment: But when doing these things, it doesn't seems to work, it display's only the last line, it can display 1 endless long line, but i need to display all the lines, and that doesn't work with these commands, thanks anyway, but it didn't seem to work ;)

Comment: @sralse: I can assure you it **does** work. Please show **how** you're using it **exactly**.

Comment: more < file.txt

Also just more
and type, but it does onley seems to show the last line in a file
but when typing in cmd it DOES work, but when in programmed in batch it doesn't work so ... ;(

Comment: I just tested it with a batch file using `more MyFIle.txt`, and it works fine whether run from a command prompt or double-clicking the batch file. Double-clicking does in fact close as soon as 100% is shown; if you want the window to stay open, add a `pause` on the line after using `more`.